# blazor server Menu

Tags: blazor

Agregar una nueva pestaña al menú de Blazor server si se cumple una condición, soy nuevo y estoy empezando no entiendo muy bien la mecánica de blazor pero me gustaría que me puedan ayudar otra duda que tengo es sobre donde puedo comprar un curso de blazor server para poder aprrender muchas gracias

```
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Marsys Vessel Server</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Admin
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Engines">
                <span class="oi oi-vertical-align-top" aria-hidden="true"></span> Engines
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-project" aria-hidden="true"></span> Tanks
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Bunker1">
                <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> Bunker #1
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Prueba">
                <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> Bunker #2
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

este seria un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer crear un int NuevaPestaña=5; si un if nuevapestaña > 1 crear la pestaña no se como pasar la variable de code{} a la seccion del menu muchas gracias por su apoyo

```
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Marsys Vessel Server</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Admin
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Engines">
                <span class="oi oi-vertical-align-top" aria-hidden="true"></span> Engines
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-project" aria-hidden="true"></span> Tanks
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Bunker1">
                <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> Bunker #1
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Prueba">
                <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> Bunker #2
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        if(nuevapestaña>1){
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Prueba">
                <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> Bunker #3
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        }
    </nav>
</div>
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    int Nuevapestaña = 5;
}
```

Comment: Esto `if(nuevapestaña>1){` debe ir con una `@` y `nuevapestaña` se debe escribir igual que como la has declarado, es decir con `N` mayúscula. `@if(Nuevapestaña>1){`

Comment: Muchas gracias el @ funciono osea que debo poner ese indetificador cada vez que quiera hacer operaciones logicas, bueno muchas greacias.

Comment: Como cierro esta pregunta y como te doy los puntos por tu respuesta soy nuevo en este foro.

Comment: ¿Seguro que `nuevo en el foro`? Porque según tu perfil, `Miembro desde hace 4 años, 9 meses`. Por otro lado, en la parte inferior donde está la respuesta, a la izquierda hay un check, dale click ahí para aceptar la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: este perfil de mi hermano cuando estudiaba la carrera pero el ya no vive en casa y deje su computador en casa y es el que yo ocupo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente te falta la `@`.

El lenguaje utilizado para generar vista se llama [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) y es una mezcla de HTML y C#. Para utilizar código C# debes comenzar por una `@`

El algoritmo de uso de la `@` es algo enredado, creo que es mejor con unos ejemplos

#### Imprimir el contenido de una variable

Simplemente se usa la @

```
@mivariable
```

#### Ejecutar un bloque

Aquí el bloque puede tener 2 formas:

```
@{
  //código C#
}

// o tambien:

@función{
  //código C#
}
```

Ejemplo para el caso 1

```
@{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int suma = a + b;
}
```

Ejemplo para el caso 2

```
@if ( a > 2 ) {
  //algo
}
```

Aquí viene lo enredado, y es que tu necesitas usar UNA sola `@` por bloque (lo que esta dentro de `{ }`) y además puedes usar código HTML dentro

```
@for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <h2>Numeros</h2> //PUEDO USAR HTML
    if (i % 2 == 0)  //NO ES NECESARIO USAR LA @
    {
        <span>@i es PAR</span> //Es necesario usar la @ para imprimir el valor de la variable "i"
    }
    else
    {
        <span>@i es IMPAR</span>
    }
}
var i=2; //Esto es un error, porque está fuera del bloque, debo volver a usar la @{}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esa explicación es muy buena gracias